# How to convert JSON string to javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I searched for this topic, and I can't seem to find the right way to parse the JSON string to read the objects.

Here is my code

```
$.getJSON("<url>", 
function(data) {

alert("success!"+data);

});
```

outputs:

```
success![object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Firebug shows correct response, and when I click JSON tab I see all the objects.

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery triggers the JSON parsing for you because you're using `$.getJSON`. If you want to see the original string, just do a `$.get()` request instead. Then you can do `var parsed = $.parseJSON(data)` to get it parsed. (I assume this is jQuery code.)

Comment: Yes it is jQuery. I will try your suggestion, but I would like to know what is wrong with my approach.., when I alert data[0].key, I get undefined, where as with data[0], I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @user: You no longer have a String. jQuery has triggered the parse for you, so you now have regular javascript objects. To access their content, you either need to iterate over them in a `for/in` loop, or you need to have pre-determined knowledge of their content. If for some reason you don't know what the keys are, then use `$.get()` and look at the string. Or, instead of `alert(data)`, do `console.log(data)` and open your browser's console. This will let you inspect the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON = JavaScript Object Notation precisely because it is the way to declare object literals in JavaScript. The data parameter is already a Javascript object (in your case an array of objects) that you can access as:

```
data[index].fieldname
```

Comment: Hi, when I alert data[0], I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] where as when I use data[0].key , I get undefined... :(

Comment: Hint one: download the JSON file and see the object structure. Hint two: access that structure properly. E.g. if it is an array of arrays, access as `data[i][j]` etc... Maybe you could show us your JSON data

Comment: Your hint made me realize it was 2D array. I am able to see the data! Thanks :)

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/A_3488-2D-Arrays-in-JavaScript.html

Answer (score 4):

When a JSON string is parsed, it is turned into a Javascript object.  If you use a string method on an object, the string `[object Object]` is returned.

You need to use object property access methods instead (e.g. `alert(data.somekey);`).

Comment: Maybe `data[0].somekey` since it looks like an Array of Objects.

Comment: I generated the data using JSONArray, of the form [{"key":"value...}, {}...]

Comment: @user It's hard to answer your question without knowing what you want to do with your data. You'd need to add a real-life example...

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `alert()` for debugging in cases like this if you have Firebug available. Use `console.log(data)` and you will get direct insights into your JSON data.
In this case you'd have realized that there's absolutely nothing wrong :D .

Answer (score 0):

enter your json string here, and click on the created tree view On the top left you will see how you can access it
[link text](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log('data=>',data)` if you want to see what is inside of you objects.